# Convert linq query to Generic string array

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I know that I can cast my linq query to an array or list but this doesn't seem to help.

Here is my query:

```
  var bracct = from DataRow x in _checkMasterFileNew.Rows
    select new {BranchAccount = string.Format("{0}{1}", x["Branch"], x["AccountNumber"])};
```

When I attempt to convert it to a list or array:

```
  List<string> tstx = bracct.ToList();
```

or this:

```
string[] stx = bracct.ToArray();
```

If give me this:

[image]

I am assuming I need to change my query but I'm not sure the best way to hanlde it. How do I get it to a generic collection of strings?

Comment: Why the downvote??? There is nothing wrong with this question. It is clear and gives plenty of information. Seems lately, people are down voting everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is creating an anonymous type with a single member `BranchAccount`.  If you actually just want a `string`, then just select that instead:

```
var bracct = 
    from DataRow x in _checkMasterFileNew.Rows
    select string.Format("{0}{1}", x["Branch"], x["AccountNumber"]);
```

And now your `ToList()` call will return `List<string>`:

```
List<string> tstx = bracct.ToList();
```

Comment: This is what I was needing. Tyvm!

Answer (score 3):

It won't work because you've created an anonymous type with 1 property which is a string. Instead, If all you want is to convert it into a `List<string>` do:

```
var bracct = (from DataRow x in _checkMasterFileNew.Rows
              select string.Format("{0}{1}", x["Branch"], x["AccountNumber"])).ToList();
```

And if using c# 6.0 you can use string interpolation:

```
var bracct = (from DataRow x in _checkMasterFileNew.Rows
              select $"{x["Branch"]}{x["AccountNumber"]}").ToList();
```

Comment: Have you ever tried interpolation on linq query? I mean, does it work if you try `... select ${x["Branch"]}{x["AccountNumber"]}` as it actually uses `String.Format()` anyways.

Comment: @uteist - haven't testes that part of the answer but compiler recognizes it correctly so I assume it is ok. And ya- string interpolation is basically a string.format

Comment: Now, that looks way more elegant. +1 to me :)

Comment: @GiladGreen sorry, I saw the answer above before I saw this one, even though this one is correct also. I did upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

You must select the property you are assigning the string to before performing `ToList()`, or remove the anonymous type and `select string.Format()` directly

Try this:

```
List<string> tstx = bracct.Select( x => x.BranchAccount ).ToList();
```

Comment: Although this would technically fix my issue, the believe the better way would be the answer given by Gilad and Charles.